# How to filter table by if any of the columns contains a x value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

How to write a where clause that filters any rows that equal to `Not or NO`.

The challenge is, the data has to many columns, so I need to avoid writing a specific where for each column like  `where a not in ("Not","NO") and b a not in ("Not","NO")` and so on.

That doesn't work because there are too many columns.

Table:

```
name    a    b    c     d    e   (so on... there are lots more column)

joe    good  yes  Not   NO    yes
mike   yes   yes  yes   good  well 
louis  Not   yes  NO    yes   NO 
jhon   yes   NO   well  Not   yes
```

Desired output:

```
name    a    b    c      d    e 

mike   yes   yes  yes   good  well
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table` t
where not regexp_contains(format('%T', t), r'(?i)"not"|"no"')
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Only down side is it take a while to run but thats fine

Answer (score 1):

Equality has symmetry to it, so you could have also done

```
where 'Not' not in (a,b,c,d,e) and 'No' not in (a,b,c,d,e);
```

Comment: Thank you, never knew it could be done backwards like field + condition + column names.
It is great to know that

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

Sample Table:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].MainTable
```

[image]

Solution:

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = 'MainTable';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql +
CASE 
    WHEN @sql = '' THEN ''
    ELSE ' AND '
END + '[' + cols.COLUMN_NAME +']' + ' NOT IN (''Not'',''No'')'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols
WHERE cols.TABLE_NAME = @TableName;

select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @sql 
execute(@sql)
```

Result:

[image]